# Cannot resolve method 'build' in 'FormLoginConfigurer'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data, spring-authorization-server

I want to test my end point, in spring security I am new idk what will be solution .

### Cannot resolve method 'build' in 'FormLoginConfigurer

No candidates found for method call http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth .requestMatchers("/").permitAll() .anyRequest().authenticated()) .formLogin() .build().

```
package com.mohacel.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder ;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    //authentication
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder){
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("mohacel")
                .password(encoder.encode("Admin@123"))
                .roles("USER","ADMIN")
                .build();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("tushar")
                .password(encoder.encode("User@123"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return  new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin()
                .build();
    }


}
```

**class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer<org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity>**

```
package com.mohacel.security.controller;

import com.mohacel.security.dto.UserDto;
import com.mohacel.security.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<String> greeting(){
        String message = "Welcome the Word of Spring REST API";
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<String> register(@RequestBody UserDto userDto){
        String registerInfo = service.registerUser(userDto);
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(registerInfo, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/allUser")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDto>> allUser(){
        List<UserDto> allUser = service.getAllUser();
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(allUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(){
        String message = "Your are eligible to ";
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

what will be the solution

Comment: why not just read the documentation for spring security before asking here? `.formLogin(withDefaults());` as pointed out in the FormLogin chapter in the docs.... https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html